# Getting blanks while reading a CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to read a csv file and store in a hasmap. Below is the code I am using.

```
$data | ForEach-Object {
  $ht = @{}
  $_.psobject.Properties |
    #Get only the grouped properties (that have a number at the end)
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\d+$' } |
    #Group properties by param/group number
    Group-Object {$_.Name -replace '\w+(\d+)$', '$1' } | ForEach-Object {
      $param = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'param' }
      $value = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'value' }

      #If property has value
      if($value.value -ne ""){
        #Add to hashtable
        $ht.add($param.Value,$value.Value)
      }
    }

  $ht
}
```

Below is the output for `$ht`. I am getting 1 `$null` value for one of the field `OrgId`.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
{orgId, }                      {1000002, $null}
type                           CSVFile
codepage                       MS1252
agentId                        00000208000000000002
name                           infa_param_file_Pravakar
dateFormat                     MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
database                       C:\\Program Files\\Informatica Cloud Secure A
```

Sample CSV:

```
"param1","value1","param2","value2","param3","value3","param4","value4","param5","value5","param6","value6","param7","value7","param8","value8","param9","value9","param10","value10","param11","value11"
"orgId","000002","name","infa_param_file_Pravakar","agentId","00000208000000000002","dateFormat","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss","database","C:\\Program Files\\Informatica Cloud Secure Agent\\main\\rdtmDir\\userparameters","codepage","MS1252","type","CSVFile","","","","","","","",""
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample (with headers) of the actual csv file?

Comment: Added as a link. Please let me know if you are unable to access.

Comment: Please don't link to external file hosting sites

Comment: I am not sure how to upload to stackoverflow. Appologies. Sample csv added.

Comment: You missing one extra `,""` in data line. Also `value11` will match `\w+(\d+)$` as following: `value1(1)`, so after replace you will got `1` not `11`.

Comment: @PetSerAl  right. I changed the missing "". Is there a better way to handle the second issue?

Comment: @PetSerAl do u mean `\w+(\D+)$` ??

Comment: @live2learn No, I mean replace `\D+` (anything not digit) to nothing.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: `-replace '\D+(\d+)$', '$1'` should do the trick as well

Comment: Good call. Forgot that \w matched digits. Fixed bug original answer too. :-) sample data didn't have enough params for it to show up during testing.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks a lot for your help!